Inline CSS for background-color not showing
I have a bootstrap table-striped table. In this case, odd rows typically have gray background. Bootstrap CSS version is v5.3.2.
But if I add style="background-color: red" directly to the <td> elements, cells on odd rows shows a slight darker tint than the even rows. Why would the background still appear differently between odd and even rows? I would have thought inline styles have the highest specificity and is the final.
It's the same on both Chrome and Edge browsers.
Below is a very simple example (as originally provided by one of the answers), showing that the cells in odd rows being slightly darker, despite having inline style setting the background to red.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: red">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: red">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: red">3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

The example output is below:

The odd rows show #e82516, while the even rows show #f42717.

The code you have shown does not demonstrate the problem you have described so please create a runnable snippet which you have tested definitely does demonstrate the problem.

@AHaworth, I've modified the question using the example given in one of the answers... The problem can be demonstrated easily.

I believe that the .table-striped class applies background color on the <tr> element, and not the <td> element.
I tried to replicate your issue, but was in vain. But I did see that when I tried to set the same for <tr> it did not override the color.
I tried changing some things in the devtools, and found that setting --bs-table-bg to none like this:
<table class="table table-striped " style="--bs-table-bg:none;">

i was able to fix it. This might cause other issues, so make sure to check if other row backgrounds are unaffected in your case.
Check your markup for issues as well since I wasn't able to get your exact issue replicated.

The problem is due to --bs-table-bg-type and --bs-table-striped-bg being defined as styles via table.scss. They seem to override inline CSS for background-color. As you've mentioned, the correct way is to override those. You can't reproduce the problem because somebody overrode --bs-table-striped-bg in our code with gray instead of semi-transparent black, as is defined in bootstrap.  Specifically to answer my question, I needed <td style="--bs-table-striped-bg: none; background-color: red">1</td>

could you modify your answer based on the updated question? If possible, could you also include the explanation that bootstrap defines styles --bs-table-bg,  --bs-table-bg-type and --bs-table-striped-bg. The fact that `--bs-table-striped-bg`` is semi-transparent (alpha: 0.05) black, applies a bit of black tint on the red background color. Hopefully this explanation can help others facing the same issue. Thank you.
